# How to add properties to Control designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm making my custom control with a designer (inherited from `ControlDesigner`).

I know how to add verbs by using `DesignerVerbCollection`. But I don't know how to add verbs and dropdowns related to Control properties.

Here is an image explaining what do I mean.

[image: Designer]

My Visual Studio version is in Spanish, so I could translate some examples:

- Editar elementos... > Edit items...
- Editar columnas... > Edit columns...
- Editar grupos... > Edit groups
- Vista > View
- ImageList pequeña > Small ImageList
- ImageList grande > Large ImageList

I know `Edit items...` is a verb, but I don't know how to open the collection.

View and ImageList properties are comboboxes. I don't know how to add comboboxes.

**EDIT:** I googled before asking the question, but I didn't find anything related to my problem.

**EDIT 2:** I don't want to add the ListView properties to my control. I simply need to add my custom properties to my custom control's designer.

**EDIT 3:** I checked out https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Design/System/Windows/Forms/Design/ListViewDesigner.cs,c996e9fb36c3ed37 but .NET source code shows bodyless code.

Comment: added imagelist from tools to your control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DesignerActionList` is the thing you was looking for.

```
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner 
{   
    private DesignerActionListCollection _ActionLists;
    private MyControl myControl;
    
    public MyControlDesigner() : base() 
    {
        _ActionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
        _ActionLists.AddRange(base.ActionLists);
        _ActionLists.Add(new MyActionList(this));
    }
    
    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists => _ActionLists;
    public override void Initialize(IComponent component) 
    {
        base.Initialize(component);

        if (Control is MyControl)
            myControl = (MyControl) Control;
    }
    
    public class MyActionList : DesignerActionList
    {
        private MyControlDesigner Designer;
        
        public MyActionList(MyControlDesigner Designer) : base(Designer.Component) => this.Designer = Designer;
        
        public string MyProperty 
        {
            get => Designer.myControl.MyProperty;
            set => Designer.myControl.MyProperty = value;
        }
        
        public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems() {
            DesignerActionItemCollection items = new DesignerActionItemCollection();
            // Replace Behavior with your property's category (if applicable)
            items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("MyProperty", "My property", "Behavior", "This is my property in the designer"));
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

`DesignerActionPropertyItem` for properties

`DesignerActionMethodItem` for actions

For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey0f414.aspx